# Can't connect to QGIS 2.18 plugin repository

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

QGIS 2.18.15 installed from KyngChaos packages on OSX 10.11.5, the official plugin repository reads "unavailable" and I can't grab any more plugins. I'm not using a proxy, I tried reinstalling and changing networks, no dice.

[image: plugin unavailable]

I think it's an authentication issue because when I try to add the same url without HTTPS, it connects to the non-secure one (but doesn't let me install anything because of an SSL error). Also throws "Error reading repository: QGIS official plugin repository. SSL handshake failed."

[image: but non-https works]

[image: Error reading repository: QGIS official plugin repository SSL handshake failed]

I can manually add plugins and they work, but that's kind of annoying; anyone see this error before?

Comment: I do. I tried also the 302 version and it's working as expected. The problem looks like being only to 2.18

Comment: Corresponding mailing list thread: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Plugins-repository-unavailable-for-2-18-tc5365597.html